# How to activate LFS Support button in Eclipse?

Tags: java, git, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, git-lfs

I am running Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12.0) in my Windows 8.1 x64 PC. I have downloaded Git 2.28.0 portable package and included the location till `bin` in the `PATH` environment variable. When I type git in cmd, it is working fine. Also, I have downloaded git lfs package, and copied it to the same bin folder of Git. I initialized it and my global `.gitconfig` now looks like below;

```
[filter "lfs"]
    required = true
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
```

I have checked LFS support in my local repository, and found that its working fine. But, When I open eclipse and go to Git configuration (Window > Preferences > Team > Git), it is showing that LFS is not enabled / active. Below is the screenshot;

[image: Git Config Window]

I would like to activate this feature. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you installed _Java implementation of Git - optional LFS support_ (via _Help > Install New Software..._ and working with [`http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates`](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates))?

Comment: @howlger I installed it and not the button is active. Thanks, and if you can post this as answer, I will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/)'s LFS support:

In ***Help > Install New Software...*** work with [**`https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates`**](https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates) and install ***Java implementation of Git - optional LFS support***.